# Angular 2 click event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular

My have a web project and using angular 2 my different pages used click event don't have any problem but new page created then click event give a error in new page.

**This Error**

> TypeError: self.parentView.parentView.context.changedItem is not a
>   function
>       at View_SiteConfig3.handleEvent_0 (/AppModule/SiteConfig/component.ngfactory.js:137)
>       at View_SiteConfig3.eval (core.umd.js:12399)
>       at HTMLTextAreaElement.eval (platform-browser.umd.js:3223)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:3971)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:154)
>       at HTMLTextAreaElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:335)

**site-config.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items1; let i = index;" class="col-sm-4">
    <button (click)="changedItem(item)">Test</button>
</div>
```

**site-config.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from '@angular/http'

@Component({
    selector: 'site-config',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/site-config.html'
})
export class SiteConfig implements OnInit {

    items1: number[] = [1,2,3]

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    public changedItem(item) {
        //My Codes This Here
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Solved problem this method;**

> My project worked. Problem is ts file not compiled then give a "is not
>   a function" error

Comment: Could you publish changedItem method?

Comment: only changedItem method doesn't work and all my codes above without app.ts file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's an error from a piece of code you don't provide.

I reproduce your code :

The view:

```
<pre *ngIf="current">{{current}}</pre>
<div *ngFor="let item of items1; let i = index;" class="col-sm-4">
  <button (click)="changedItem(item)">Test</button>
</div>
```

The class content:

```
items1: number[] = [1,2,3]

current: number;

ngOnInit() {
}

public changedItem(item) {
    this.current = item;
}

constructor() {
}
```

Here's a working Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/ZGI1FNB8RWN9BnnPnKgJ?p=preview

Can you provide more code ?

Comment: My project worked. Problem is ts file not compiled then give a "is not a function" error. thanks for helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**site-config.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items1; let i = index;" class="col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" (click)="changedItem($event, item)">Test</button> <!-- add type="button" -->
</div>
```

**site-config.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from '@angular/http'

@Component({
    selector: 'site-config',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/site-config.html'
})
export class SiteConfig implements OnInit {

    items1: number[] = [1,2,3]

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    public changedItem(event: any, item: number) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Your code...
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
}
```

Comment: angular/http is deprecated https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#http